# Найти самое длинное и короткое название

Tags: python

задача найти самое короткое и длинное название города(формально). Выводится самое короткое название, а длинное нет. Не могу понять в чём проблема. Заранее спасибо.
Вот код :

```
x1 = str(input())
x2 = str(input())
x3 = str(input())

x11 = len(x1)
x22 = len(x2)
x33 = len(x3)

xmax = max(x11, x22, x33)
xmin = min(x11, x22, x33)

if xmin == x11 or xmin == x22 or xmin == x33:
    if xmin == x11:
        print(x1)
    elif xmin == x22:
        print(x2)
    else:
        if xmin == x33:
            print(x3)
elif xmax == x11 or xmax == x22 or xmax == x33:
    if xmax == x11:
        print(x1)
    elif xmax == x22:
        print(x2)
    else:
        if xmax == x33:
            print(x3)
```

Comment: `str(input())` избыточно, поскольку input ничего кроме строки не возвращает

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не совсем ясно, почему в строке `elif xmax == x11 or xmax == x22 or xmax == x33:` используется elif. Замените на обычное if

Answer (score 5):

```py
short, *_, long = sorted([
    input(),
    input(),
    input(),
], key=len)
print(
    f'{short = }',
    f'{long = }',
    sep='\n'
)
```

Comment: Красиво, но `f'{short = }'` работает только с какой-то свежей версией питона, не помню с какой

Answer (score 0):

```
d = {len(x): x for x in (input() for _ in range(3))}
print('short = ', d[max(d)], 'long = ', d[min(d)])
```